# Some questions about encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

I have some questions about encoding. I have some files in various types and encoding. Only text files (.txt, .csv, .xml) can have  byte order mark or am I wrong? In first method I want to prepare file : change encoding, remove pramble or not , at secund I want to only use :

```
 File.WriteAllBytes("testFile.csv", fileBytes);
```

I don't want to send encoding to second method, so should be bom at every file? or It will be saved with unicod encoding. 
To convert encoding I want to use Encoding.Convert method but after converting there is no bom at file, so Is it better to use streamReader and StreamWriter with source and dest encodings?

Comment: The last time I checked txt files contain pure text. No header, no bom, no encoding.. finding the correct encoding is therefore an art, not a guaranteed thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML format marks its encoding to its root node but it's just a notation. Real encoding can be different.

In my opinion, use same encoding to all of output and input files. Unicode is good choice as you mentioned.

If you cannot handle the input files encoding because they wrote by other person, try UTF-8 for them. Almost text editors are using UTF-8 as default encoding. `File.WriteAllBytes()` as well.